# Calculating SPI with Lognormal Distribution in R?Drought

Tags: python, r

I am working on calculating the Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) using the lognormal distribution in R. However, the spei package does not seem to support this distribution. I would like to know how I can calculate SPI with the lognormal distribution in R.

[image]

I have also tried using the fitdistr function from the MASS package to estimate the parameters for the lognormal distribution, but I'm unsure about the next steps to calculate SPI based on these parameters.

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mohamed Naim! (1) Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: (2) Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.